# Google Maps Engine Service Account with Google APIs .NET

Tags: google-oauth, x509certificate, google-api-dotnet-client, google-maps-engine

I'm working on a service that requires authorization server to server to Google Maps Engine.

https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/oauth/serviceaccount and https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth?hl=en#service_account explains how to do this.

But, in the Google APIs. NET yet, do not have the class of service for Google Maps Engine API, then I would like to take part of the flow of the library, because I do not want to do all the hard work of managing JWT.

I think something like:

```cs
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"key.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
    new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
    {
        Scopes = new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/mapsengine" }
    }.FromCertificate(certificate));

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.googleapis.com/mapsengine/v1/projects");
credential.ApplyAuthenticationToRequest(request);
```

I want to use a pure HttpWebRequest, however using the certificate.

Could someone help me?

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll recommend you to do the following:

1. First of all use the [Microsoft.Net.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) package. Google.Apis depends on it, so you already have it installed.
2. Try to use the following code:

> ```
> // Create HTTP client using ConfigurableMessageHandler.
> // More details available in:
> http://contrib.google-api-dotnet-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.8.0-rc/documentation/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Http_1_1ConfigurableMessageHandler.html.
> var httpClient = new HttpClientFactory().CreateHttpClient(new CreateHttpClientArgs
>     {
>         ApplicationName = "YOUR_APP_NAME",
>     });
> // Add your credential as interceptor.
> httpClient.MessageHandler.ExecuteInterceptors.Add(credential);
> // Create the request.
> var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(
>     "https://www.googleapis.com/mapsengine/v1/projects");
> ```

I DIDN'T TEST it, but it should do the magic for you :)

Comment: Awesome!! I also tested it with the POST and works fine. Thanks a lot @peleyal!